# Sonarqube - Run scan on develop branch vs master in the Community Edition

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, static-analysis, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I have installed the **community edition version 9.x.x** of SonarQube. I have 2 branches `develop` and `master`. All active code checkin's etc. go into the `develop` branch.

I run the scan manually on the command line using the command:

`sonar-scan Dsonar.projectKey=XXX -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.host.url=https://mysonarwebserver.com -Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

It seems to be scanning the `master` branch in all cases, I want it to scan the `develop` branch instead.

Things already tried which do not seem to work:

- Making the default branch from `master` to `develop`
- Setting sonar.branch.name = `develop` *(This is not allowed any more in the community edition)*

Help appreciated.

Comment: `master` is only a label. Add something only to `develop`, execute a scan and you will see  in SonarQube UI that `master` contains that code.

Comment: You can enable the branch support for the community edition by installing this open source extension https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin